# ¿Qué tan efeciente es usar system en php?

Tags: php

Hola a todos tengo esta duda debido a que últimamente mientras practicaba con php y python estuve pensando en la efeciencia del programa al hacer eso, me refiero a, ¿es buena opcion usar la funcion `system` para ejecutar programa en los que es más fácil hacer algo en php? Yo (en mi caso) uso la función `system` para usar expresiones regulares, y eso lo hago con python, lo que básicamente sería de esta forma:

```
ob_start();
ob_clean();

$text = escapeshellarg('Cualquier texto');

system("python3 file.py $text");

$result = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();
```

Y ya después eso lo proceso con mi archivo python e imprimo el resultado para que php lo pueda recibir, ahora, mi pregunta es ¿hacer eso a grandes rasgos puede afectar al redimiento de la página (el ejecutar programas de esta forma), y si si cómo puedo arreglar eso? Desde ya gracias :).

Comment: Si puedes hacerlo con PHP yo lo haria todo con él.  Lo digo porque en hostings compartidos es probable que te encuentres con que te capan algunas funciones que acceden al sistema, para evitar malware que normalmente las usa para ello.  Si es para uso corporativo, es decir, que no acceden desde Internet, pues lo que te sea más cómodo, pero en el caso de python tendras que sumar el tiempo de interpretación de PHP con el python, si no esta compilado, y eso no se si va a beneficiar la rapidez de lo que pretendas.

Comment: @masterguru ¿pero. por ejemplo en este caso, las expresiones que hago en python son muy complejas, y con php sería mucho mas complicado y puede que el código se vea mal, en este caso qué sería mejor?

Comment: No se si seria tan complicado con PHP, no he visto las expresiones, pero te recuerdo que en PHP tienes las [funciones PCRE](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pcre.php) que lidian con expresiones regulares de forma bastante eficiente. Quizás seria buen momento para aprenderlas ya que si te funcionan en Python no deberian ser demasiado dificiles de implementar usandolas.

Comment: Si de verdad quieres saber qué es más eficiente, te recomiendo que tú mismo te hagas un benchmark para comprobarlo, será la mejor manera. Replica tus expresiones en PHP y móntate un pequeño test sencillo, primero capturas el tiempo actual, luego lanzas un bucle de 1000 o 10000 ciclos de llamadas a los métodos de las expresiones regulares y por último al tiempo actual le restas el anterior tiempo que guardaste en una variable. Con eso sabrás exactamente el tiempo que tardan en ejecutarse... luego haces lo mismo con las ER de python y miras qué diferencia de tiempos tienes